# GPSBabel KML document has incorrect name

Tags: kml, gpx, gpsbabel

I'm using GPSBabel to convert GPX tracks in a directory to KML linestrings using the following:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal
for %%i in (C:\Users\...\*.gpx) do (    
    gpsbabel.exe -t -i gpx -o kml,points=0 %%i %%~di%%~pikml\%%~ni.kml
)
```

This works great, except that all KML documents have the name "GPS device". I'm new to GPSBabel and after reading what appears to be the relevant documentation I'm not sure if it's possible to provide the output document's name. So far my best option seems to be post-processing with a find / replace operation but I'd like to avoid this.

How can I tell GPSBabel what to use as the KML document name?

Comment: Are you sure that the name is wrong or the name of the track used in the source data? Have a look inside your gpx files. That said, KML driver https://www.gpsbabel.org/htmldoc-development/fmt_kml.html does not seem to have an option for changing the names. Nor the gpx driver https://www.gpsbabel.org/htmldoc-development/fmt_gpx.html.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but yes, each GPX has a different name

Comment: Ok, then it must be the default in GPSBabel. Have you tried ogr2ogr https://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html with the libkml driver https://www.gdal.org/drv_libkml.html?

Comment: I haven't - the question is focused on GPSBabel. libkml may be able to solve my problem but building from SVN (as instructed by the documentation) could end up being significantly more effort than I am able to commit to this side-project. I may have to look at find / replace with a Windows build of sed.

Comment: You can just download http://gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1911-x64-gdal-mapserver.zip, unzip, run "sdksell" and you'll have everything ready.